# Rails distinct user records, sorted by time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have a query to get the latest post from each user I follow. Like so:

```
query = Post.select("DISTINCT ON (user_id) *")
      .includes(:likes).includes(:comments)
      .where(user_id: followings)
      .where(silently_deleted: false)
      .order(user_id: :desc, created_at: :desc)
```

Problem is that the posts won't order by date. And I can't really do `sort_by` because we're paginating.

Is there a way to order by `created_at` while still being to preserve the uniqueness?

Comment: Can you share the SQL output? Also some sample data and desired output? "It doesn't order by date" isn't very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
query = Post.select("DISTINCT ON (user_id) *")
  .includes(:likes).includes(:comments)
  .where(user_id: followings)
  .where(silently_deleted: false)
  .order(user_id: :desc)
  .order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

You need to add the table name explicitly because likes and comments tables also have the column name created_at

Answer (score 0):

You might use a **self-join** to select the last post for each user.

For each post, this LEFT JOINs all posts by the same user, that are created later (have a higher `id`) than the current post. The following `where` condition then selects only those records which have NO later post, i.e. effectively selecting the last post for each user.

Refer to [this blog](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) post for other possible solutions. The best solution depends largely on the posts table size.

```
query = Post
  .joins("left join posts p on p.user_id = posts.user_id and p.id > posts.id")
  .where("p.id is null")      
  .includes(:likes).includes(:comments)
  .where(user_id: followings)
  .where(silently_deleted: false)
  .order(user_id: :desc, created_at: :desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group + having:

```
Post.group(:user_id).having('posts.created_at=MAX(posts.created_at)')
```